# Where are the credentials in Google Sign In?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I've followed Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) for their new Google Sign In but I can't seem to find the `credentials` their referring to in the statement:

> After Google returns an ID token, it's submitted by an HTTP POST method request, with the parameter name credential, to your login endpoint.

In the html I followed their example as follows:

```
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id={keys.client_id}
        data-login_uri={`${basePath}/auth/google`}
        data-auto_prompt="false"
      ></div>
      <div
        className="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-size="large"
        data-theme="outline"
        data-text="sign_in_with"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      ></div>
```

And it correctly posts to my node server, but where are the `credentials`? I don't see them in the headers, cookies, path, anywhere. I do see the `g_csrf_token` the docs allude to in the python code, but I don't see the credentials anywhere.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

[data-login_uri](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-login_uri) shares the ID token is in the body of the POST request to your `/auth/google` endpoint:

```
POST /auth/google HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

credential=ID_TOKEN
```